# How to store the iteration value for next cycle in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

I am planning to assign incidents automatically in servicenow. This is working fine. But whenever next iteration is running it again stating with first employeeid which i have provided. But i want to store the employee detail where it finished in last iteration. This is my working code

```
# cat working_inc.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests, json, csv
import sys, ast
login=(userid,"password")
#open_incidents_url="URL to connect"
open_incidents_url="URL to connect"
response=requests.get(open_incidents_url,auth=login)
response=response.json()['result']
print(response)
employee_number=["empid1","empid2", "empid3","empid4"]
j=0
if len(response) < 1 :
    print("No New Tickets in OPENSHIFT / OSFI - SPT Servicenow group")
else:
    for i in response:
        print (i["number"])
        body = {"assigned_to":employee_number[j],"number": i["number"]}
        o=requests.post("https://optum.service-now.com/api/now/import/u_incident",auth=login,data=json.dumps(body))
        print(o.status_code)
        if j == 3:
            j=0
        else:
            j=j+1
```

In my code when first time it ran suppose it assign 3 inc to 3 empid but when next time i am running again it will start from first employee but i want to start with 4th empid

Comment: python has 'enumerate' function for this: geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the data between iterations then you have to save it some where.  Your program starts with 0 every time through.

```
# cat working_inc.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests, json, csv
import sys, ast
login=(userid,"password")
#open_incidents_url="URL to connect"
open_incidents_url="URL to connect"
response=requests.get(open_incidents_url,auth=login)
response=response.json()['result']
print(response)
employee_id_fn = 'last_id.txt'
if not os.path.exists(employee_id_fn):
  j = 0
else:
  with open(employee_id_fn, "r") as stream:
     j = int(stream.read())

employee_number=["empid1","empid2", "empid3","empid4"]

if len(response) < 1 :
    print("No New Tickets in OPENSHIFT / OSFI - SPT Servicenow group")
else:
    for i in response:
        print (i["number"])
        body = {"assigned_to":employee_number[j],"number": i["number"]}
        o=requests.post("https://optum.service-now.com/api/now/import/u_incident",auth=login,data=json.dumps(body))
        print(o.status_code)
        j = (j + 1) % 4
    with open(employee_id_fn, "w") as stream:
       stream.write(str(j))
```